# web worker throwing 404 when executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

My project structure looks like

```
js
  /client.js
  /script1.js
  /webWoker.js
node_modules
.gitignore
index.html
```

The `main.html` has it included as well in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/webWoker.js"></script>
```

My `script1.js` looks like

```
if (window.Worker) {
    console.log("uri: " + document.documentURI);
    var myWorker = new Worker("myworker.js");
    myWorker.postMessage("hello");
    console.log(myWorker);

    myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
        result.textContent = e.data;
        console.log('Message received from worker: ' + result.textContent);
    };
}
```

and my `webWorker.js` looks like

```
onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Message received from main script');
    var result = "#27ae60";
    console.log('Posting message back to main script');
    postMessage(result);
};
```

I use `node.js` for this project and run it via `npm start`, and when I run this in browser I see

```
script1.js:81 GET http://localhost:8080/webWorker.js 404 (Not Found)
execute @ script1.js:81
img.onload @ script1.js:64
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to include the worker script in your main page (it's even a bad idea), but the URI you pass to `new Worker(URI)` is relative to the current documentURI.

So in your case, it should be `new Worker("/js/webWorker.js");`.

Comment: `scipt1.js:81 GET http://localhost:8080/webWorker.js 404 (Not Found)`. I still get that even though I changed the path and removed it from `html` file

Comment: @daydreamer try `/js/webWorker.js` You don't show where is `main.html`

Comment: Hello @Kaiido, even `/js/webWorker.js` does not seem to work. I have updated my question with path to `index.html`.

Comment: can you try to log `document.documentURI` on the line before you call `new Worker` ? Also, can you check you are not using a cached version of your `script1.js` ? (e.g run it in an incognito window)

Comment: I updated my code to include `uri` in `console.log`. I get back value as `uri: http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Then a relative path `/js/webWorker.js` should point to `http://localhost:8080/js/webWorker.js`, I don't understand what's happening here... What if you try to load an image from this same folder : `var img = new Image(); img.onload = _=>console.log('path is correct'); img.src = '/js/someFile.png';` ? And what if you type the absolute path ? (`new Worker('http://localhost:8080/js/webWorker.js')`). What if you remove all browser plugins / user-scripts etc.

Comment: `new Worker('http://localhost:8080/js/webWorker.js')` is working, strangely, when I changed it to `new Worker('js/webWorker.js')`, even that started to work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Kaiido Could you please elaborate more on "You don't have to include the worker script in your main page (it's even a bad idea)"
Why do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: @oshan2csd this is referring to `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/webWoker.js"></script>`. This means that either their worker script is polyglot and can be executed from both the main context and the worker, implying it's probably less clear to read, or it means that it throws an error.

Comment: I got a 404 because I misspelt my "worker.mjs" filename. It was "woker.mjs"!